# How does sizeof() work for char* (Pointer variables)?

Tags: c

I have a C code:

```
char s1[20];
char *s = "fyc";
printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(s1), sizeof(s));
return 0;
```

It returns

```
20 8
```

I'm wondering how does the 8 come from, thanks!

Comment: What platform are you compiling on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sizeof(s1)` is the size of the array in memory, in your case 20 chars each being 1 byte equals 20.

`sizeof(s)` is the size of the pointer. On different machines it can be a different size. On mine it's 4.

To test different type sizes on your machine you can just pass the type instead of a variable like so `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(char*), sizeof(char[20]));`.

It will print `4` and `20` respectively on a 32bit machine.

Comment: Just had a doubt what if we are to find sizeof(*s) ? it is giving me 1 byte but it should have been 3 bytes for "fyc". Kindly clarify this doubt.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar That's because `char* s` is pointing to the first character of "fyc". So if you printf `*s`, you get the first character of "fyc" which is 'f'. Individual character weighs 1 byte. That's why you got 1 byte.

Answer (score 15):

`sizeof(char *)` is the size of the pointer, so normally 4 for 32-bit machine, and 8 for 64-bit machine.

`sizeof` an array, on the other hand, outputs the size of the array, in this case, 20*sizeof(char) = 20

One more thing, you should use `%zu` for `size_t` type in `printf` format.

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(s1), sizeof(s));
```

Answer (score 11):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of a **type**. The operand of `sizeof` can either be *the parenthesized name of a type* or an *expression* but in any case, the size is determined from the type of the operand only.

`sizeof s1` is thus stricly equivalent to `sizeof (char[20])` and returns *20*.

`sizeof s` is stricly equivalent to `sizeof (char*)` and returns the size of a pointer to `char` (*64 bits* in your case).

If you want the length of the C-string pointed by `s`, you could use `strlen(s)`.

Comment: `sizeof` can very well be used to evaluate the size of a **variable**: `char c[2]; printf("%uz", sizeof(c));` is correct C and returns `2`. But propably it's just the wording you use, that made write this comment.

Comment: @alk What I meant is that the `sizeof` operator is either applied to an *expression* or a parenthesized name of a type. when it's applied to an expression, it's the type inferred from this expression that is used by the compiler to determine the value of the `sizeof`.  The fact that the expression is a variable or a literal is not relevant since it's only the type of the expression that is used, not the value. I will rephrase to make my point more clear.

Answer (score 5):

8 is the size of a pointer, an address. On 64 bit machine it has 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a 64 bit computer, the memory addresses are 64 bit, therefore a 64 bit (8 bytes x 8 bits per byte) numeric value must be used to represent the numeric pointer variable (char*).

In other words, sizeof() works the same way for pointers as for standard variables. You just need to take into account the target platform when using pointers.