# Why does the string I copied using strncpy have junk instead of the last character?

Tags: c, string, malloc, strlen, strncpy

I malloc'd an array of structures called "locations". In said structure is an element called "country". I created a string you can see below that holds "United States" in it. I malloc'd space to hold the string (it's required that I do so) and attempted to use strncpy to place the string into the malloced space.

This works elsewhere in my code with strings that are read in from a file, but not for this string which I declared directly.

When I print out the result, it says the structure is holding "United State(error symbol)"

So in place of the s at the end of "United States" is the error symbol.

The error symbol looks like a small box of ones and zeros.

```
char *US_string = "United States";
locations[0].country = malloc(sizeof(US_string));
strncpy(locations[0].country, US_string, strlen(US_string));
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks for any help! And please try not to be too hard on me, I'm a first year CS major. Just trying to get this bug out of a lab.

Comment: You want `country` to have `malloc` `strlen(US_string) + 1` bytes so that you can properly [null terminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) your string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298172/how-does-sizeof-work-for-char-pointer-variables

Comment: `man strncpy: [...]The  strncpy()  function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n  bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mallocing need to be adjusted by adding `1`to account for `'\0'`. Moreover sizeof(US_string) will give size of pointer, which may be different from actual string size. Hence

```
locations[0].country = malloc(strlen(US_string) + 1);
```

and missing `locations[0].country[strlen(US_string)] = '\0'`

Comment: EDIT: apparently you changed your comment, I'll look into the new one.

Comment: Appreciate the help! Appears to be working well now! However, I didn't null-terminate the string, and apparently it's still fine. I don't think I need to for what I'm using it for. Though If it starts giving me trouble I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sizeof will return the pointer size, not the string size. Use strlen +1 (to account for the 0 string termination char):

```
locations[0].country = malloc(strlen(US_string)+1);
```

Comment: Even `strlen(...) + 1`