# Why is sizeof(str) is equal to 8 , when it should be equal to strlen(str)+1 ... (because of extra null char)?

Tags: c++, string, sizeof, strlen

When I print strlen(str) and sizeof()
Here is one char array:

```
const char *str = "Geeksforgeeks";
```

When I print strlen(str) and sizeof(str) it gives output as :

```
cout<<strlen(str)<<endl;
cout<<sizeof(str)<<endl;
```

output:

```
strlen(str): 13
sizeof(str): 8
```

- which should not be the case; sizeof() should return 14 because of extra null character?
- I tried this for smaller strings and sizeof() value doesn't change, still 8 ?

Comment: The return value of `sizeof` depends only on the type of the expression, and nothing else. The type of `str` is `const char *`, and the size of a pointer doesn't depend on the data it points to.

Comment: The size of a container does not depend on the container's contents. Changing the value of a variable doesn't change its size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298172/how-does-sizeof-work-for-char-pointer-variables.
The strlen returns the length of string, where as sizeof() is the size of char ptr.

Comment: David Schwartz hints at something really important about pointers in his comment: A pointer is just another data type, one where the value just happens to be a location in storage. Knowing this will help you understand why pointers sometimes need to be passed by reference.

Comment: *Here is one char array:* -- No, that is a string-literal -- pointers are not arrays.  Change that to `char str[] = "Geeksforgeeks";` and you may see the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is sizeof(str) is equal to 8

Because the type of `str` is `const char *` i.e. pointer to `const char`, and the size of pointers on your system happens to be 8 bytes.

> when it should be equal to strlen(str)+1 …

No it shouldn't, because that number is not the size of the type which is what the `sizeof` operator returns.