# Why sizeof() does'nt return the right length of a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

So, I'm trying to implement a XOR encryption as follows :

```cpp
string XOR(char *data, char *key) {
    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(data); i++)
    {
        data[i] ^= key[i % sizeof(*key)];
    }
    cout << sizeof(data) << "\n";
    return data;
}
```

This is the function that will take as input `data` and `key`
The important thing here is that for each character in the array `data`, a XOR operation is made with the key, hence the for loop : `for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(data); i++)...`

The problem arises with `sizeof(data)` which returns `4` or my expcted output would be `27` (26 letters in the alphabet + the null terminator (I think)).

The program outputs this :

```
4
 #"%efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Only the first 4 letters are processed correctly.

What is strange is that `sizeof(str)` returns 27 which is corect so why `sizeof(data)` returns 4 ?

**So what do I need to change in the parameters of the fucntion `XOR` ?**

Here is the entire code :

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string XOR(char *data, char *key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) + 1; i++)
    {
        data[i] ^= key[i % sizeof(*key)];
    }
    cout << sizeof(data);
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    char clef[] = "A";
    char str[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    cout << XOR(str, clef) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Another duplicate: [Why is sizeof(str) is equal to 8 , when it should be equal to strlen(str)+1 ... (because of extra null char)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944380/why-is-sizeofstr-is-equal-to-8-when-it-should-be-equal-to-strlenstr1) (the third hit when I searched this site for `[c++] sizeof strlen`)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple : instead of using `sizeof()`, use `strlen()` like so :

```
string XOR(char *data, char *key) {
    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(data); i++)
    {
        data[i] ^= key[i % strlen(key)];
    }
    cout << strlen(data) << "\n";
    return data;
}
```

Note that in the following case :

`char str[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` , `strlen(str)` will return 26, not 27 as it would have been the case using `sizeof(str)`

Comment: Even worse, if you apply `sizeof` to a pointer (e.g. `data`) it will give you the size of the pointer, typically 4 or 8.